# how to connect to container in docker stack deploy

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use docker stack deploy to deploy a node app. This should be obvious I guess, but how do I connect to the database from the node app?

This is my sample docker file - I haven't tackled scaling each service yet, just trying to connect everything. Given this file, if I `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml dev` - then what is the correct mongo address for connection string to connect node to mongo?

```
version: '3'

services:
  node: 
    image: rgilling/rsc:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - "core"
      - "front"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "500k"
        max-file: "10"
  db1:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod
    networks:
      - core
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "500k"
        max-file: "10"
  search1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.0
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - ../../elastic/config/search1.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
      - ../../elastic/config/log4j2.properties:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/log4j2.properties
      - ../../elastic/logs/search1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/search1
      - ../../elastic/data/search1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/search1  
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - core
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "500k"
        max-file: "2"
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.3.0
    hostname: test-rep
    volumes:
      - ../../kibana/config/systest.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    networks:
      - core
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on: 
      - search1
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "500k"
        max-file: "10"
  mail:
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    hostname: test-mail
    networks:
      - core
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"
      - "1025:1025"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "500k"
        max-file: "10"
networks: 
  core:
    driver: overlay
  front:
    driver: overlay
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

docker will create a network accessible name for each container. in your case it would be `db1`.

`mongodb://user:password@db1/my-database`

you can also add a `links` section to your docker-compose, which lets you specify a name to map to `db1`.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links

```
node:
  links:
   - db1:mongo-server-name
```

it's generally best to add the `links` section anyways, so docker knows which containers are supposed to connect to each other.

```
node:
  links:
   - db1
```

no need to rename in this case. just specify the container that `node` connects to

Comment: I'm having some unrelated issues that are stopping me from testing this out, but when I run stack deploy it says:  "Ignoring unsupported options: cap_add, links" - are you sure links works with stack deploy?

Comment: never mind I got it working. For anyone interested, the address is indeed db1, but I don't think "links" work with stack deploy. There is a service called routing mesh that routes the address to any container running that service (in the case of autoscaling). I haven't tried anything more advanced like using a dns, but perhaps using 'hostname' option in the docker-compose still works with stack deploy - I didn't try it.

Comment: Wrong answer, As official document says: `links not supported for docker stack deploy or the deploy key.`

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is actually wrong `links:` is not supported in docker stack deploy 
see this link : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#not-supported-for-docker-stack-deploy

you can connect to another container by using the linking **container's service name** in the swarm suppose two services mysql_service and java_service is running in swarm then inside the java_service container try `ping mysql_service` to verify whether it is connected

or you can use aliases to have alternative hostname for a service in a network

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases

Answer (score 0):

If you run app through `docker stack deploy` - all containers of one service can see each other.

So, for your case to connect to the DB you should just write:

`db1:27017`

(where db1 - is your DB container name)

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy